# Android - client causing "Connection reset by peer" exception

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I would like to know, whether there is a possibility that the implementation of the client side, could be causing this IOException? As far as I know, this exception is caused by the remote site, sending the RST packet, effectively shutting down the connection. Whatever answers I have come up with so far, all claim that this is the server's fault.

But the problem is the following. I am communicating with the server via TCP sockets and the android app is the client. The communication used to work prefectly, but after making some modifications (to the client side ONLY), I keep getting this exception.

I am having a hard time pinpointing the source of the problem, because the updates I've made had nothing to do with the communication implementation. I've only added another query for the server to handle.

Is it possible to produce this exception from the client side(that my code, could cause the remote side to produce this outcome)? Perhaps by overloading the server with requests? Or maybe Android is closing my sockets, by itself? Or perhaps I am somehow closing the sockets, but that would probably produce a different type of exception.

Any advice on the matter would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say anything about those questions you are making without seeing the source code. In my own experience, sometimes you look too deep and can't see the obvious error right in front of you. send the code at least the part that produces the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem wasn't in the client implementation afterall. The server was actually ending the connection, after a certain query had been executed. To anyone who may be experiencing a similar issue (where you think the client side has an error, despite the obvious fact stated by the program, that it's the server's fault), I suggest you double check the server for possible timeouts and such.